# Use one list item as a variable in another list item in the same list in R

Tags: r, list

I want to do something like the following in R:

```
a <- list(
  x = 2 + 7,
  y = x + 8
)
```

It appears that this is not possible, though, or at least not in this way. Is there any way to use the value of `x` in defining `y`? I know I could define two objects independently, `x` and `y`, then do `list(x, y)`, but I'd rather skip creating a lot of extra objects in my workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr::lst`, we can do this

```
library(dplyr)
lst(x = 2 + 7, y = x + 8)
```

-output

```
$x
[1] 9

$y
[1] 17
```